# MVC5 AD FS Integration

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, web-services, adfs

I am very very very new to AD FS (0 experience).

I am trying to integrate with an AD FS Server, on MVC5 (.NET Framework, not .NET Core!!!)

here's the code from my startup.auth.cs:

```
  public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

        app.UseWsFederationAuthentication(new WsFederationAuthenticationOptions
        {

            MetadataAddress = "https://dev.adfs.server.com/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml",
            Wtrealm = "https://localhost:44360/", // my website 
            Wreply = "https://localhost:44360/Search", // where to redirect after login

        });
    }
```

The error I get is: An error occurred. Contact your administrator for more information.

See [image]

What could possible be the reason?